# TCP server on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, tcp, matlab-deployment

I can't TCP from MATLAB to MATLAB

Server Code:

```
 t = tcpip('192.168.1.14', 8000, 'NetworkRole', 'Server');
    set(t, 'InputBufferSize', 900000);


fprintf('waiting for client \n');
fopen(t);
fprintf('client connected');
```

MATLAB waiting for client when I use fopen(t)

when I'm trying to connect from another PC on the same network I use this Code:

```
tc = tcpip('192.168.1.14', 8000,'NetworkRole','Client');
fopen(tc)
```

on the Client PC return no errors after `fopen(tc)` 'that's mean the Server is working fine

but on the Server PC .. It still waiting for client without detecting the Client and jump to `fprintf('client connected');`

when I tried both of these codes on the same PC using different versions of MATLAB it worked fine on the server and Client ..
.......
there is another problem there .. I don't need the code to be paused for waiting a client I need 
there is no Client:
do something 
If client exist do something else

Thank you