# Starting Python TCP server Over MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, tcp, matlab-deployment

I tried to create remote TCP server on MATLAB but it didn't work then I posted my problems there and there is no one answered me :

[TCP server on MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653591/tcp-server-on-matlab)

so I decided to start TCP server with Python language on the matlab .. I lost hours to create this code :

```
clear
clc
import py.textwrap.wrap
import py.socket.socket

socket=py.importlib.import_module('socket')
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);




server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, py.str(1))

a=py.int(1000);
server_addr=py.tuple({'192.168.1.6',a});


server.bind(server_addr);
server.listen(50)
connection_1=connection(1)
data = connection_1.recv()

data = connection.recv(1024)
```

every things went fine until I wrote `data = connection.recv(1024)`
I can't read the received data coz the variable `connection` return with type of tuple and the accepted type of data is class 'socket._socketobject'

client code:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = ('192.168.1.6', 1000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'connecting to %s port %s' % server_address
sock.connect(server_address)
sock.sendall('1')
```

the latest error was:
No appropriate method, property, or field 'recv' for class 'py.tuple'.
so I have to convert type of the variable 'connection' to be accepted to 'recv()' function

this is how MATLAB see the variable 'connection_1'

```
connection_1 = 

  Python tuple with no properties.

    (<socket._socketobject object at 0x0000000020963730>,
```

Thank you